# How to make an array element the first entry in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr = explode(',', $str);
$arr[0] = 'Please select value';
```

The above makes key 0 the last element ,how to make it first except sort the `$arr` ?

Comment: Your code will overwrite the first entry in the array... is this intended?

Answer (score 2):

```
array_unshift($arr, 'Please select value');
```

use this if you want to add this value on start at first element of array.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_unshift`](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php):

```
array_unshift($arr, 'Please select value');
```

If you want to retain the array keys, you have to go hacky. I don't recommend this though, but it should work:

```
$arr = array_merge(array("something" => 'Please select value'), $arr);
```

The new element has to have *some* key that doesn't exist in `$arr`, it doesn't have to be `"something"`. If you'd use a numerical index, `array_merge` would renumber the items starting from zero. So it has to be a string if you really need it to work this way.

Working example:

> http://codepad.org/0ZcPpppe

Comment: But I don't want to modify the numeric keys,just the order.

Comment: @wamp please provide sample input and output

Comment: So you want to have a '-1' key?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make a difference whether it's the first or last element if you are accessing it via `$arr[0]`. (arrays in PHP are really maps). An array that's like:

```
array (
    [1] => 'Hello',
    [0] => 'World
)
```

For the most part, will behave just like:

```
array (
    [0] => 'World',
    [1] => 'Hello'
)
```

But if you insist in having it in the beginning you can use [`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)